# Deleting log tables

Tags: logs

Using CiviCRM 4.6.9.

While exploring debugging options I clicked on "Yes" for the "Logging" option in the Administration "Misc" page.  That created hundreds of tables prefixed with "log_" in the CiviCRM database.  This isn't what I wanted.

I've turned off logging, but the tables are still there.  Is it OK to manually delete any table beginning with "log_"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rob - yes you should be fine to do that. Backup prior of course. Is it the fact you have tables, or the size of them that is the issue?

Comment: Tables and data consume resources, so I would say that it's both.