# Is it safe / wize to empty civicrm_log table

Tags: database, logs

Pretty similar to [this question](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/7041/deleting-log-tables), we've moved LOG_tables to another database; however, there is civicrm_log table among "main" tables still (not sure why, since it keeps log records and, in theory, belongs to LOG_tables group). Size of civicrm_log table in our case grows pretty fast (80M at time i'm writing this), second biggest table in the db. We may need these records in a future, but moving table out of current setup makes it inaccessible for civi searches / reports. Keeping it makes simple database backup (via phpmyadmin) somehow troublesome. So, in case deletion will be chosen, is it safe to flush it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing stopping you flushing it but you will lose transitional information and any log data unless you also have audit logging switched on. You could keep a backup of it in a separate database if you need to stop it becoming a problem.

Comment: Is the info in civicrm_log really just a log? Not critical for any other core functions? I'd like to routinely flush this because of the size...

Comment: I'm pretty sure its just a log based on the fact that if you switch on full audit logging then all the log tabs switch to the log_ tables and the civicrm_log table is no longer used to display the audit information. The only edge case might be memberships but I'd need to have a further look to see if any information is necessary, I'm 99% sure it isn't.